# ContainerView embedded segue called programmatically and not in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, container-view

I have a relatively complex view controller and another not that complex(but not light either) view controller. I want the complex one to have a simple one as a child and I use container view and storyboard for that. However, when I navigate to my complex view, there is a noticeable delay in transition.

Using a Time Profiler, I figured out that if I remove another vc from container view UI will be smooth again.

So I wonder, what is the way to fill the container view with another vc programmatically somewhere in viewDidAppear, for example (the delay would be less noticeable for the user) ?

Comment: According to your investigation what was actually making it slow?

Comment: The view controller that is embedded into the container view. It's loading methods etc.